# Java convention: when referring to coordinates, do I name methods and variables with "location" or "position"?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, conventions, convention, coding-style

My program deals with a lot of coordinates and I want to keep things consistent throughout my program to improve readability, but I am stuck on whether to use the word "location" or "position".

Java itself seems to be conflicted on this; the `java.awt.JFrame` class has both  `setLocation()` and `getMousePosition()`, which each use different words to refer to the `java.awt.Point` class.

I had a look in Oracle's Java Coding Conventions document but I saw no mention of how to refer to coordinates.

Is there a standard naming convention for this, or should I just choose the one I prefer and stick to it?

Comment: I think you should just choose one and stick to it.

Comment: This depends on the naming conventions used in your business domain; it's not really a programming language naming convention issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should choose a naming convention and follow it within your team. Although naming convention is important, I think the situation described is too much of a purism. Java has no notion of coordinates in its naming convention. Just follow the general rules for getters/setters and so on.

On a more philosophical note:

- `location` - describes the location (x,y,z).
- `position` - could imply position in reference to something (vertical, beneath, above, facing North)

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. I agree with what you said, I just asked the question to see if there were any pre-existing conventions that I should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `Location` makes more sense, when it comes to English:

A method called `Locate()` would be more efficient than `getPosition()`

But, in retrospect, "Locate" has a very vague title; according to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/locate)

> 1. to identify or discover the place or location of: to locate the bullet wound.
> 2. to set, fix, or establish in a position, situation, or locality; place; settle:

So "Locate" could mean to set, or get a location.

---

My main opinion: `Loca`tion should be used in `Loca`l positioning, or relative, and position should be global (A child object VS its parent)